# Scheme Binomial function using Pascal's Triangle

Tags: scheme

The binom procedure is suppose to return a function such that `((binom n) k a b)` is the kth term in the binomial expansion of `(a + b)^n`.

This is my code.

```
(define (pascal row col)
  (cond ((= col 1) 1)
        ((= row col) 1)
        (else (+ (pascal (- row 1) (- col 1)) (pascal (- row 1) col)))))

(define (binom n)
  (lambda (k a b)
    (cond ((or (= n 0) (= n k)) 1)
          (else (binom (pascal k n)))) 1))
```

I am trying to fix the binom function. I think the formula is `(n k) * a^k * b^(n-k)`. How should I write it in Scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused with the formulas, you're mixing up n, k, row and col.
I'd recommend writing down the formulas you want to program, name the variables on paper, then write the procedure using the same variable names.

With binom though, I'm not sure what your intent was.
Binom returns a lambda, that's all well and good.
But then in that lambda you make a recursive call to binom,
again returning a lambda? And then at the very end you basically ignore
the result you get from this and return 1?
In its current form binom will never return anything other than a lambda or 1.

Here's what I think you want:

```
(define (pascal n k)
  (cond ((< n k) (error "not defined: k > n"))
    ((= k 1) n)
    ((= k 0) 1)
    ((= n k) 1)
    (else (+ (pascal (- n 1) (- k 1)) (pascal (- n 1) k)))))

(define (binom n i a b)
  (* (pascal n i) (expt a (- n i)) (expt b i)))
```

Comment: what could be the reason for the original assignment demanding it defined as `((binom n) k a b)`? Could there be some shared computations to factor out there, to avoid the repetition?..

Comment: I was a bit confused about that too. As far as I know, doing it like that has no real advantages. Unless there is another formula im not aware of. It would kinda make sense to have ((binom n a b) i) so you can map easily map it, but otherwise I don't see the point.

Comment: for just one call there is no difference, yes. my guess is that it is aimed at producing all terms of the expansion of (a+b)^n at once more efficiently. you'd need to calculate the whole row and return a closure with that row in it. ---  kudos for fixing the OP's formula, too!